# why am I not able to access object's property

Tags: scala

A class is defined as follows

```
class InvalidPasswordException(msg: String, cause: Throwable = null)
  extends ProviderException(msg, cause)
```

I am doing a match on it but I am unable to access the `msg` property. Why? It is not public?

```
x match {
                    case e:InvalidPasswordException =>{
                      Unauthorized(Json.toJson(JsonResultError(e.msg))) //msg is undefined
                    }
                    case _ => {
                      InternalServerError(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Internal Server Error. Reason "+x)))
                    }
                  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are defining both properties but no visibility to neither of them. Try changing the definition to this:

```
class InvalidPasswordException(val msg: String, val cause: Throwable = null)
  extends ProviderException(msg, cause)
```

That way you are providing the accessor methods as well.
One other thing to add: try to avoid using null in Scala; use Option instead as to reduce possible NullPointerExceptions in your code to a minimum.